# Sql Query to Linq

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

How would I convert this query from SQL to Linq:

```
SELECT status As 'Status',
       count(status) As 'Count'
FROM tbl_repair_order 
WHERE contract = 'con' and 
      (status = 'Parts Arr' or 
       status = 'NA' or 
       status = 'New Call' or 
       status = 'Parts Ord' or 
       status = 'Parts Req' or 
       status = 'F Work')
GROUP BY status
```

---

Update

Thanks Guys, this is the code I used. Tested and returns the same as above:

```
        List<string> statuses = new List<string> { "Parts Arr", "NA", "New Call", "Parts Ord", "Parts Req", "F Work"}; 

        var result = (from x in db.tbl_repair_orders
                     where x.CONTRACT == strContract
                        && statuses.Contains(x.STATUS)
                     group x.STATUS by x.STATUS into grouping
                     select new { Status = grouping.Key, Count = grouping.Count() });

        return result;
```

Comment: I think you should heed Eamon's warning in the second bullet point of his answer.

Comment: Actually, the `.Contains()` call does correctly translate to LinqToSql (and maybe to the EF as well) - http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/

Comment: After reading that link, it's also worth noting that using an array instead of List will generate an IN statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    string[] statuses = new string[] { "Parts Arr", "NA", "New Call", "Parts Ord", "Parts Req", "F Work" };
    var x = (from ro in db.tbl_repair_order
             where ro.contract == "con"
                && statuses.Contains(ro.status)
             group 0 by ro.status into grouping
             select new { Status = grouping.Key, Count = grouping.Count() });
```

I don't know if the syntax is correct (especially the last two lines) but it should be pretty close.

I added the 0 between group and by based on Eamon Nerbonne's correction in the comments.  Also, thanks to Ryan Versaw for the link explaining List and arrays for generating IN clauses.

Comment: It should be `grouping.Key` - besides that, I think it looks correct.

Comment: The main difference I had in my version (similar enough I'm not posting a new answer) is to use a list.
`List<string> statuses = new List<string> { "Parts Arr", "NA", "New Call", "Parts Ord", "Parts Req", "F Work"};` 
Then change the where conditions to this: `ro.contract = "con" && statuses.Contains(ro.status)`

Comment: @Ryan, thanks for the Key tip, I also noticed that after posting it.

Comment: @Ryan, do you mind if I edit the answer to include your alternative?  I like that better than the mass of ORs.

Comment: Go for it! It might be good to leave your existing version as well, just point out that the functionality would be the same.

Comment: while you're at it, if you include any arbitrary value between "group" and "by", it'll work.  However, you should probably not use the List.Contains syntax - IIRC that'll break linq-to-sql translation should you wish to use the query there.

Comment: @Eamon, I don't understand what you mean by including a value between group and by.

Comment: @Andy: the syntax is `group <expression to include in group> by <group key> into <groupName>`

Comment: @Andy: gotta run, I hope syntax this got across, in any case, you might want to add a warning about the risk of using List.Contains, in which case my answer below becomes redundant.

Comment: @Eamon, thank you.  That was stumping me last night when I was working on a similar query.

Comment: @Andy: it's weird anyhow; 90% of all such group by queries I'm not interested in the individual items, merely in their aggregates: but there is no way to express that; instead you need to uselessly (and in a potentially memory-intensive fashion) create collections of items per group and in post-processing to the aggregation (i.e. grouping.Count()).

It's a shame!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you wire up your table's appropriately, something like

```
var statusCounts =
    from row in youDbNameHere.tbl_repair_order
    where row.contract == "con"
        && (row.status == "Parts Arr"
        || row.status == "NA"
        || row.status == "New Call"
        || row.status == "Parts Ord"
        || row.status == "Parts Req"
        || row.status == "F Work")
    group 0 by row.status into g
    select new { Status = g.Key, StatusCount = g.Count() };
```

...and I see Andy beat me to it ;-)

Notes:

- You need to include an expression between "group" and "by", this expression is will be evaluated to form the set of values accessible under the group's key (in your case it's irrelevant, so a zero is fine).
- If you wish to use Linq-to-Sql or Linq-to-Entities (or some other IQueryable implementation), be aware that your code will not execute directly in C#, but rather be translated (as it should be) into sql -- so avoid using .NET specific calls that cannot be translated, as these will generally cause a run-time exception or (rarely) cause the resulting query to be partially evaluated client-side (at a potentially hefty performance cost).

Answer (score -1):

As far a s converting SQL statements to equivalent Linq to SQL statements you should check out the [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) tool which does just that. I don't think this app is good to use for re-writting your whole application but it can be a very useful tool for learning Linq to SQL in general.